# How to program a condition (if, ifelse) in r that chooses one or more elements of a vector?

Tags: r, if-statement

How to program a condition in r that chooses one or two elements of a vector?
I tried to use `ifelse()` but it demands to have the same length both in test and `yes`, `no` arguments.

```
 object <- sample(c("A","B","C"),1)

ifelse(object %in% c("A","A"), c(1,2),

       ifelse(object=="B", 1,

              ifelse(object=="C",2,NaN)))
```

I want to obtain `1,2` when object is `"A"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object is of `length` 1, we can use `if/else`

```
f1 <- function(obj) if(obj == 'A') 1:2 else if(obj == 'B') 1 else if(obj == 'C') 2 else NaN
f1(object)
#[1] 1 2
```

Or with `switch`

```
f2 <- function(obj) switch(obj, 'A' = 1:2, 'B' = 1, 'C' = 2,  NaN)

f2(object)
#[1] 1 2

f2('B')
#[1] 1
f2('C')
#[1] 2

f2('D')
#[1] NaN
```

Comment: It always return one single value of the vector, I want to obtain `1, 2` when `object %in% "A"`

Comment: @Sinval Can you please show a small reproducinle example and expected output so that I can test it.  Your values `c("A", "A")` is confusing